# Jersey REST service: Detect if URL ends with a questionmark

Tags: java, url, request, jersey

## Detecting Questionmarks

I need to implement a protocol where the user may provide a question mark appended to an URL in oder to retrieve additional information about the provided resource. I am aware that the questionmark after the URL resource indicates query parameters. Unfortunately this protocol does demand question marks at the end of the URL as an indicator.

## Implementation

I implemented the service using Jersey.

```
    @GET
    @Path("{/service/")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String resolve(@PathParam("uri") String fqn,
                          @PathParam("ark") String arkLabel,
                          @Context UriInfo ui, @Context HttpServletRequest hsr) {

        // here i need to test of the url ends with ?
        if (url.endsWith("?")) {
            // to something
        }

    }
```

## The Problem

All the methods provided from `UriInfo` and `HttpServletRequest` i found stripe away the last questionmark, if it is not followed by a query parameter. How can I get the raw URL, including a question mark at the end?

## Solution

Based on the answer from @cy3er I could solve the problem. The following snipped does the trick. The method `getQueryString()` returns null if the URL did not contain any query, i.e. if there was no `?` attached to the URL. Then I can assume if the string is empty, that there was only one `?`, because the query is empty. In the third caswe I can check if the only query parameter passed is one `?`, which corresponds to two `??` in the URL.

```
    if (hsr.getQueryString() == null) {
        this.logger.info("Normal link");

    } else if (hsr.getQueryString().equals("")) {
        this.logger.info("one ?");

    } else if (hsr.getQueryString().equals("?")) {
        this.logger.info("Two ??");
    } else {
        this.logger.info("None of the above");
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to know if there is a single questionmark at the end ?

Comment: @ToYonos because the protocol which  I am implementing  demands the possibility to retrieve Metadata about the content,  by appending a ?  to the URL. I am aware that this question mark character does carry a function, namely initiating the list of parameters. Unfortunately I have to provide this feature, as the standard defines it like this.  I would also prefer something like '/q'  or '?q' or whatever other indicator.

Comment: Something like `?q` will be indeed a better idea. So you are implementing the protocol and this protocol defines this `?` rule for retrieving Metadata ? It's very bad conception.

Comment: @ToYonos I completely agree, this is not my choice. If you are interested, have a look at the ARK identifier scheme managed by the California Digital Library https://confluence.ucop.edu/display/Curation/ARK The approach is called ARK inflections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `getQueryString` method of the `HttpServletRequest`, if it's null there wasn't any questionmark. 
See [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getQueryString())

Comment: Thanks cy3er, your tipp was right. I actually tried it but as the query string is empty, I did not see it in my output and did not realize I could check against the empty string instead of null. Great!